# Find the Slope of the tangent line: y= x-x^3

Tags: calculus

Find the Slope of the tangent line I am having a problem with the instructions since another book solved the question in a odd way. Please look over my work and tell me if my answer is correct:

[image]

Comment: $-x^2+4x-3=-(x-1)(x-3)$

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is right. It seems that you do not know the concept of a derivative yet so, you will have to do a similar thing:
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{4x-x^2-3}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{-(x-1)(x-3)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1}-(x-3)=2$$

Comment: Yes, knowing the differentiation rules, this task is very easy. If you need to proof them first, it gets lengthy.

Comment: You rearragned it and then factored the numerator, duh! What do you mean when you said I do not understand the concept of derivative? Also isn't the answer -2?

Comment: The answer is $2$. Because the derivative of the function gives exactaly the slope of the tangent line in the point: $$f(x)=4x-x^2 \implies f'(x)=4-2x \implies f'(1)=2$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
Apply L'Hospital rule. Then you will get the answer.

Comment: Based on the level of this question, it looks like OP either just got to derivatives or is just about to get to them.  And you want him/ her to use l'Hôpital?

Comment: If he knows then he can answer this if he doesn't other answers are there. The objective of this site is to share your thaughts, that is what I think I have done.

Comment: Absurd. Clearly completely useless for OP. Perhaps he could express the result as a contour integral as well? Or maybe higher cohomology groups could be brought into play?

Comment: May be..... But that is far away from my solution. If he doesn't then can ask me any question. The absurdness depends on him. Anyway the others gave him the solutions previously, so you don't worry about this.